# Tabularx and decimal alignment with dcolumn

Tags: tables, tabularx, dcolumn

I am trying to implement decimal alignment on a regression table using tabularx. I am using the dcolumn package to do it, but there are two problems: (i) only two out of three columns are decimally aligned, and (ii) a column is not aligned for integer variables, in my case the Number of Observations. Can anyone help me? I have tried using the siunitx package with tabularx, but it didn't work.

All solutions are welcome!

Thanks.

Code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{bigstrut}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{endnotes}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}                                 % Font output type
\usepackage{ae,aecompl}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bbm}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{datetime}
\usepackage{tabularx} % provides a column type called "X" that should satisfy your professed need to have several equal-width columns
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usdate
%\usepackage{rotfloat}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{colortbl}
%\usepackage[pdftex]{color,graphicx}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{float}
\floatstyle{plaintop}
\restylefloat{table}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf, labelsep=period, justification=centering, font={small,doublespacing}, skip=0pt]{caption}%define table values
%\usepackage[labelfont=bf, labelsep=period, center, scriptsize]{caption}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
%\usepackage{indentfirst}
%\bibliography{refs}
\usepackage{hyper}
%\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
%\usepackage{bibtex}
\usepackage[comma, sort&compress, longnamesfirst]{natbib}
\usepackage[flushmargin,hang]{footmisc}
\setlength{\footnotemargin}{0.5em} % just to show clearly equal output
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X} % handy shortcut macro
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X} % handy shortcut macro
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X} % handy shortcut macro
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D{.}{\cdot}{#1}} % and yet another handy shortcut macro


\begin{document}


\begin{table}[h]
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2} %Vertically expands the table
%\addtolength{\tabcolsep}{5pt}%Horizontally expands the table
\begin{threeparttable}
%\begin{small}
\centering
\def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi}
\caption{In-sample forecasting monthly excess stock returns ($R_{i,t+1}-R_{f,t+1}$).}
      %\begin{tabular}{lccccccc}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{l l*{3}{d{-2}}}% the tabularx package gives you: the total width as a first parameter, and a new column type X, all X columns will grow to fill up the total width.
        \toprule
    Dependent Variable: $R_{i,t+1} - R_{f,t+1}$ & \multicolumn{1}{r}{(1)}   & (2)   & (3) \\
    \midrule
    Constant     &      -0.001        &      -0.001        &       0.001        \\
            &     (-0.10)        &     (-0.09)        &      (0.16)        \\
    $R_{m,t} - R_{f,t}$     &       0.111\sym{*} &       0.122\sym{**}&       0.113\sym{*} \\
            &      (1.92)        &      (2.09)        &      (1.91)        \\
$X$      &      $-1.301^{*}$ &      -1.296\sym{*} &      -1.308\sym{*} \\
            &     (-1.92)        &     (-1.91)        &     (-1.95)        \\
$Y$       &       5.900\sym{**}&       5.889\sym{**}&       5.357\sym{**}\\
            &      (2.24)        &      (2.23)        &      (2.01)        \\
$Z$       &       0.304        &       0.232        &       2.318        \\
            &      (0.03)        &      (0.03)        &      (0.26)        \\
$W$ &                    &      -0.001\sym{**}&      -0.001\sym{**}\\
            &                    &     (-2.44)        &     (-2.70)        \\
$A$      &                    &                    &      -0.056        \\
            &                    &                    &     (-0.45)        \\
N obs       &        8981        &       \multicolumn{1}{c}{8981}        &        8991        \\
$R^2$       &       0.014        &       0.015        &       0.015        \\
    \bottomrule
    %\end{tabular}%
    \end{tabularx}%
\begin{tablenotes}[flushleft]%[para]
\scriptsize
\item
\item \sym{*} Scaled by 100.
\end{tablenotes}
  \label{panel reg_full sample}%
%\end{small}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: you can't use `tabularx` without an X column, it has no way to stretch the table. Just use tabular (forcing the columns apart should be a non-aim anyway)

Comment: the Nobs row is aligned in the third column but not in the first two as you have removed the d alignment with `\multicolumn{1}{c}{8981} ` (it may be that is the best thing to do as the integer is unrelated to the real numbers above so alignment doesn't really help)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try to trim examples to just the required packages, in this case your example just needs

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tabularx} % provides a column type called "X" that should satisfy your professed need to have several equal-width columns
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
%\usdate
\usepackage{dcolumn}

\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D{.}{\cdot}{#1}} % and yet another handy shortcut macro


\begin{document}
```

You have specified 5 columns, the first two `l` and the next three `d` but you only have 4 columns of data, so the third `d` is never used, which explains why you only get decimal alignment in two columns.

`tabularx` works by changing the width for *line breaking* in **X** columns you have no line breaking here and no X so it can not work as intended. Just use `tabular` (If you *really* want to over-separate the columns you could use `tabular*` but it just makes it harder to read the table)

Here I left two of the 8981 aligned as integers but I think column (2) with it centred as you had it is better.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
%\usdate
\usepackage{dcolumn}

\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D{.}{\cdot}{#1}} % and yet another handy shortcut macro


\begin{document}


\begin{table}[h]
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2} %Vertically expands the table
%\addtolength{\tabcolsep}{5pt}%Horizontally expands the table
\begin{threeparttable}
%\begin{small}
\centering
\def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi}
\caption{In-sample forecasting monthly excess stock returns ($R_{i,t+1}-R_{f,t+1}$).}

\begin{tabular}{l *{3}{d{-2}}}% the tabularx package gives you: the total width as a first parameter, and a new column type X, all X columns will grow to fill up the total width.
        \toprule
    Dependent Variable: $R_{i,t+1} - R_{f,t+1}$ & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(1)}   & 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{(2)}   & 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{(3)} \\
    \midrule
    Constant     &      -0.001        &      -0.001        &       0.001        \\
            &     (-0.10)        &     (-0.09)        &      (0.16)        \\
    $R_{m,t} - R_{f,t}$     &       0.111\sym{*} &       0.122\sym{**}&       0.113\sym{*} \\
            &      (1.92)        &      (2.09)        &      (1.91)        \\
$X$      &      -1.301^{*} &      -1.296\sym{*} &      -1.308\sym{*} \\
            &     (-1.92)        &     (-1.91)        &     (-1.95)        \\
$Y$       &       5.900\sym{**}&       5.889\sym{**}&       5.357\sym{**}\\
            &      (2.24)        &      (2.23)        &      (2.01)        \\
$Z$       &       0.304        &       0.232        &       2.318        \\
            &      (0.03)        &      (0.03)        &      (0.26)        \\
$W$ &                    &      -0.001\sym{**}&      -0.001\sym{**}\\
            &                    &     (-2.44)        &     (-2.70)        \\
$A$      &                    &                    &      -0.056        \\
            &                    &                    &     (-0.45)        \\
$N$ obs       &        8981        &       \multicolumn{1}{c}{8981}        &        8991        \\
$R^2$       &       0.014        &       0.015        &       0.015        \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}%
\begin{tablenotes}[flushleft]%[para]
\scriptsize
\item
\item \sym{*} Scaled by 100.
\end{tablenotes}
  \label{panel reg_full sample}%
%\end{small}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: as here the table is 21.4pt too wide, there are various ways to adjust that depending on the actual page size in your real example.

Comment: David, thank you for your answer, it looks great now. The only thing I'd like to change now is to adjust the width of the table to be textwidth, and tabularx does it automatically.

Comment: as I said that should be a non aim, it just makes the table harder to read, I'd just fix the heading in the first column to be 2-line say `\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}Dependent Variable:\\$R_{i,t+1} - R_{f,t+1}$\end{tabular}` so the first col isn't so wide, and call it done.